# Gitlab add a file with third party api keys and credentials

Tags: android, file, gitlab, credentials

Is there a way to copy&paste a file with credentials into gitlab? I don't want to have the files saved on the repository, is there any documentation on how to do it through terminal? I want to change the `local.properties` file on our server.

I knew how to do it with Github and Jenkins but I can't find the documentation of how to do it for Gitlab.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@carlosmaciel Do you mean like an environment variable but a file? You can do this through the UI or API. The docs are [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#file-type).